# Sphinx claiming memory is too low and my ids are null

Tags: linux, search, indexing, sphinx

I am trying to index about 3,000 document but here is what I am getting

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-0A-19-CB data]# /usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --all
Sphinx 2.0.4-release (r3135)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'catalog'...
WARNING: Attribute count is 0: switching to none docinfo
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 12288 kb
WARNING: source catalog: skipped 3558 document(s) with zero/NULL ids
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.040 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
total 1 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 5 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

I have it set to rt_mem_limit = 512M why is it telling me I dont have enough memory?

Answer (score 1):

`rt_mem_limit` != `mem_limit` - they are different variables - with different purposes.

mem_limit - is the value used by indexer during indexing
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-mem-limit
- its in the 'indexer' section of your config file.

You must have it sent too loo. Either just leave it out (to use 32M), or change it to better value.

But you also have no document_ids in your dataset. Check your sql_query actully works.